# Return n rows for each level in a column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the data frame

```
df1 = data.frame(Site=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",7)),Species=sample(1:100, size=12))
```

and want to filter the dataframe so that only the first 3 rows for each site are return. ie. returning the dataframe

```
df2=data.frame(Site=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),Species=c(3,84,45,38,39,22))
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily select the first three rows using `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df1, "Site", function(df) df[1:min(nrow(df), 3),])
```

Using `min(nrow(df), 3)` means that if the site only appears twice, we won't try and select three rows.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df1, df1$Site), function(x) x[1:3,]))
```